# Clearfix with display table instead of display block produces different results. Why?

Tags: html, css

The following HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="left">F1</div>
  <div class="spacer">Here is a div that is not floated</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.left { float: left; width: 100px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid green }

#wrapper { background: yellow }

#wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.spacer { margin-bottom: 34px }
```

Produces this:
[image]

(See: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/074tg9fj/))

As can be seen from the produced output the wrapper background (in yellow) is only as tall as `div.spacer`. Why doesn't the `#wrapper` div fully contain the floated element?

In the `#wrapper::after` rule if I change from `display: block` to `display: table` it works as expected as shown below:
[image]
Why?

**Edit:**
Also to add, if I change the `margin-bottom` to be 32px instead of 34px I get the expected result!

Comment: Because content has no content?

Comment: Why don't you write `#wrapper :last-child::after` instead of `#wrapper::after`. Then you won't even need the bottom margin. https://jsfiddle.net/074tg9fj/3/

Comment: I'm not at all sure, but here's what I _think_ is really happening. If the bottom margin to `spacer` is so large that it extends below the `left`, the float doesn't need to be cleared, so the browser doesn't "have" to do anything else. If the bottom margin is smaller though, there has to be some actual clearing performed, so the height of `wrapper` is increased to the height of its contents.

Comment: That said, I have no idea why `display:table` (or even `display:inline-block`) would work differently from `display:block`.